# jira: Find issues user resolved that then failed

Tags: search, reporting, jira

I have just started using Jira to get reports. Could someone help me get a list of issues that have had the status set to resolved by a user but have then been failed?

I am having trouble generating this report:

```
(status was "Resolved" by UserX) AND status was "Failed"
```

Using this I can get all issues resolved by UserX but it is also coming back with issues that userX resolved after someone else failed it.

Basically I want to do:

1. Find all issues set to resolved by userX
2. Find the issues in this set that have then been failed AFTER the resolved status.

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-box - you can't.

I can think of 2 ways to do this:

**Create your own JQL function** - add a function to support this.check out [Jira's Plugin Tutorial - Adding a JQL Function to JIRA](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Adding+a+JQL+Function+to+JIRA).

**Add hidden custom field to mark issues** that used to be `Resolved` and changed to `Failed`, than search for issues while matching the custom field:

```
status was "Resolved" by UserX AND status was "Failed" AND "customeField" = true
```

To populate this custom field use [AJS](http://orangoo.com/labs/AJS/) (same as jQuery) to add a function to the status field, or alternatively use the [Script Runner pluging](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) to add a post function that will update the custom field.